# Different app-name depending on configuration when app-name is localized in InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, configuration, localization, info-plist, cfbundledisplayname

We use a setup with different plists for each configuration. Like this:
*Target-Info-Dev.plist, Target-Info-Beta.plist...*

This way our configurations could have their own CFBundleDisplayName, and we can differentiate builds by app-name on device. Like this: *"DEV Appname", "BETA Appname"...*

However, now we are required to localize the app-name. We have done this by creating a localized InfoPlist.strings for each target:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "<localized-appname>";
"CFBundleName" = "<localized-appname>";
```

But since the CFBundleDisplayName is no longer derived from *Target-Info-[Configuration].plist*, we cannot differentiate the app-name for different configurations.

It should be noted that we have several *Targets* as well, for different brands of the same app, but we already got that working by haveing a separate InfoPlist.strings for each target.

Anybody have an idea of how to accomplish both localized and configuration-based app-name?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, have exactly the same issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Better Solution

1. Edit **Info.plist**, set `CFBundleDisplayName`'s value to a variable named something like `$(MY_DISPLAY_NAME)`

[image]

2. Open **'Build Settings'** tab of the **project** or **target**, add a key named `MY_DISPLAY_NAME` under **User-Defined** section(you need scroll to the bottom to find this section), then just expand the newly-added key, and set any name for each configuration as you wish.

[image]

When building your project, every variable in the Info.plist will be replaced to its value.

The solution is much simpler than the original one.

### Original Solution

I had the same requirement in my project, and then I found your question, and at last I solved it.
**Edit your projects' scheme**, add pre-action and post-action script to execute your change. Like this,

**Step 1. change app name in Build's Pre-actions**

```
str=""
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ];then
    str="dev"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "AdhocDevelopment" ];then
    str="dev"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "AdhocDistribution" ];then
    str="adhoc"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "DailyBuild" ];then
    str="rdm"
fi
perl -pi -e "s/appName[^<]*/appName${str}/g" ${PROJECT_DIR}/smd/Info.plist
```

[image]

**Step 2. Restore app name in Build's Post-actions**

```
perl -pi -e "s/appName[^<]*/appName/g" ${PROJECT_DIR}/smd/Info.plist
echo ${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE} > ~/tmp.txt; rm -f ~/tmp.txt
```

Something to explain: Debug/AdhocDevelopment/AdhocDistribution/DailyBuild are your projects' configuration names; ${CONFIGURATION} is predefined by Xcode; perl is preferable to awk and sed, which are all pre-installed on every mac OS X.

By the way, what I have done is changing appName in Info.plist, you can change your infoPlist.strings. In this way, **you just need a single Info.plist file.**

Comment: It took me a lot of elbow grease and trial-and-error to get this to work on our end for an `InfoPlist.strings` file, but I got it sorted out. `perl -pi -e "s/NameInStringsFile[^\"]*/NameInStringsFile (Extra)/g" "${PROJECT_DIR}/path/to/InfoPlist.strings"`

Comment: How do you localize MY_DISPLAY_NAME?

Comment: AFAIK you can't localize MY_DISPLAY_NAME using this method. See my answer below for a way you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955033/31605

Answer (score 2):

Since the file `InfoPlist.strings` is not just 1 single file, but is spread across multiple folders and files like so: `en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`, `de.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`. It is a bit trickier to use it for different schemes.
Here is how I localized the name of the Today Widget shared by 2 flavors / schemes of the same target. For demonstration purposes, I used 2 "flavors": `TA` and `EC`. I will refer to them in this answer.

**Step 1:**

- Create folders for each "flavor" or scheme in the target directory. Name each folder exactly as they are named in your `user-defined` scheme. Copy there the `InfoPlist.strings` file.

> This step might be tricky. What I did: I created a new folder in XCode and named it `TA`. I dragged & dropped there my `InfoPlist.strings` file, then browsed to that folder in Finder, duplicated that folder,  and renamed it to `EC`. Then, I drag & dropped it into XCode. Don't add it to any target. It is not needed.

**Step 2:**

- Remove the `InfoPlist.strings` from the target's `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase:

> Click on your project name -> Select the widget's target (ex. Today Widget) -> go to `Build Phases` -> open the `Copy Bundle Resources` -> find the file `InfoPlist.strings`, select it and press `Delete` button

**Step 3:**

- Add a new Run Script to copy the correct `InfoPlist.strings` file

Here is the script I came up with which will copy the correct file, based on the current flavor/scheme your app is running now:

```
for lng in en de es fr it nl pt-PT tr
do
  INFO_PLIST_FILE="${PROJECT_DIR}/TodayMatchesWidget/${APP_FLAVOR}/${lng}.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" 
  BUILD_APP_DIR="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}" 
  FILE_LOCATION="${BUILD_APP_DIR}/${lng}.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" 
  cp "${INFO_PLIST_FILE}" "${FILE_LOCATION}"
done
```

> This is a for loop, which iterates through all my localization
> languages. You need to put there only the languages that you support.
> Each language abbreviation should be separated by a space, nothing
> else.
>
> The only variable which you need to take care of is `APP_FLAVOR`,
> which in my case is a user-defined setting inside the project's `Build Settings`, and in my case will be either `TA` or `EC`.

Here is the final folder structure in Today Widget's folder:

[image]

**P.S:**
I assume you already have a `InfoPlist.strings` file in the target's directory. If not, just add a new `Strings File` and call it `InfoPlist.strings` and add this value inside:

`CFBundleDisplayName = "My Localized Widget";`

I hope it helps anyone out there!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can have different InfoPlist.strings for different build configurations in the same target, using only Build Settings and a few duplicate Info.plist files.

1. In your Build Settings:

   - Specify a different **Info.plist File** `(INFOPLIST_FILE)` for each configuration.
   - Set **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist**  (`STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME`) to `Yes`. On Xcode 14, it was set to `Yes` by default.
2. Create `.strings` files with the `base name of your Info.plist filename` +  `Plist.strings`.

   - For example, if your Info.plist filename is `Beta-Info.plist`, your strings file should have the name `Beta-InfoPlist.strings`. Make sure you include all of these strings file to your build.
3. Do not include an `InfoPlist.strings` file in your target.

The key to making this work is **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist** in the [Build Settings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference).

> **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist.**
> Setting name: STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME
>
> If enabled, renames .strings files whose basename matches that of the target’s Info.plist file, to InfoPlist.strings in the built product.

#### Example

Here's an example in my app which has 3 different variants (AdSupported, AdSupported-Dev, Pro) that require different app names.

1. Build settings.

[image: Build settings]

2. Strings files. They are all included in my target.

[image: InfoPlist strings files]

3. Info plist files. As usual, they are specified in the Build Settings and NOT included in my target.

[image: InfoPlist files]

Comment: while doing this, what did you do to the target Info.plist entry? did you change that as well?

Comment: Each target needs to have their own unique Info plist file, since that's how the .strings file with the actual name of the app is found. For the example in this answer, I have a specific info plist for each target.