# How to localize app name for with different build configurations?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.2

I have a project that have 3 build configurations: Debug, Beta and Release. 
These configurations have different app name each. I am doing this using a variable like `APP_DISPLAY_NAME` and using it in Info.plist file.

I need to localize these app names.

Using `InfoPlist.strings` file with `"CFBundleDisplayName"`, overrides these configuration names.

So how can I do this?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528326/different-app-name-depending-on-configuration-when-app-name-is-localized-in-info) and a couple more questions but still no result.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can have different InfoPlist.strings for different build configurations in the same target.

1. In your Build Settings:

   - Specify a different **Info.plist File** `(INFOPLIST_FILE)` for each configuration.
   - Set **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist**  (`STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME`) to `Yes`. On Xcode 14, it was set to `Yes` by default.
2. Create `.strings` files with the `base name of your Info.plist filename` +  `Plist.strings`.

   - For example, if your Info.plist filename is `Beta-Info.plist`, your strings file should have the name `Beta-InfoPlist.strings`. Make sure you include all of these strings file to your build.
3. Do not include an `InfoPlist.strings` file in your target.

The key to making this work is **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist** in the [Build Settings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference).

> **Adjust Strings File Names for Info.plist.**
> Setting name: STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME
>
> If enabled, renames .strings files whose basename matches that of the target’s Info.plist file, to InfoPlist.strings in the built product.

#### Example

Here's an example in my app which has 3 different variants (AdSupported, AdSupported-Dev, Pro) that require different app names.

1. Build settings. (I have debug & release configurations for each variant, but you could also do this with just Debug / Beta / Release.)

[image: Build settings]

2. Strings files. They are all included in my target.

[image: InfoPlist strings files]

3. Info plist files. As usual, they are specified in the Build Settings and NOT included in my target.

[image: InfoPlist files]